# Database Repair Tool Not Working doesn't support InnoDB storage engine

Tags: database, error

When we try to import products through the backend, we get an error that says foreign keys are not correct.

I went to run the Database Repair Tool. I made a copy of our current db called `dbrepair` and made a clean install db called `dbrepairref` when I try to run the tool it says "Corrupted database doesn't support InnoDB storage engine". I am not sure what to do from here to fix the problem.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.19-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10

Comment: That'll be the issue. Magento had to provide a patch to support MySQL 5.6 - as the means they used to detect the version is no longer a command in MySQL 5.6. The patch suggested below is correct, http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73070/361

Comment: I found where the db repair tool checks for innodb support and this is what it is, I'm guessing there is some kind of old mysql there as well?
[LINK TO GIST](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f64afee7bf4baa134ec4)

Comment: Also this is the installer code, We upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9, Our main issue right now is when we go tto import products through the cms system->import/export->import we get this error [LINK TO ANOTHER GIST](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1598445831dfbcac3b7e) How would the installer code have anything to do with that?

Answer (score 2):

plese read answer:-
Line 59 of the file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db/Mysql4.php

Replace:
`public function supportEngine()
    {
        $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
            ->fetchPairs('SHOW VARIABLES');
        return (!isset($variables['have_innodb']) || $variables['have_innodb'] != 'YES') ? false : true;
    }`

**with this**:

`public function supportEngine()
    {
        $variables  = $this->_getConnection()
            ->fetchPairs('SHOW ENGINES');
        return (isset($variables['InnoDB']) && $variables['InnoDB'] != 'NO');
    }`

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the database repair tool? Why would I edit the magento core code? http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool I am running a php file called magento-db-repair-tool-1.0.php

Comment: You need this fix for mysql 5.6 and higher on magento versions below 1.8 if I'm correct. You need this if you know for sure that innodb is enabled I your database server, but Magento isn't able to detect it. However it's part of installer code, doubtful that the db repair tool is reusing that code. But possible.

Comment: We upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9 when this issue showed up. I have tried everything I can think of and I can't seem to get the import functionality to work. I posted on the magento forums but have not got a response there yet. I took a look at the db repair code and its all self contained, I was assuming that some how between the upgrade the storage engine was changed. Do I just need to switch the storage engine?

Comment: lol the broken part is obviously at the top of magento-db-repair.php file